# Android Populate Spinner Content From Another Spinner

Tags: android

I am trying to populate cities by selecting a country from spinner. It should populate second spinner's content based on the first spinner's choice. My strings.xml and MainActivity.java file is like this:

strings.xml

```
 <!-- Countries -->
<string-array name="country_names">
    <item>Turkey</item>
    <item>Spain</item>
</string-array>

<!-- Cities -->
<string-array name="Turkey">
    <item>Istanbul</item>
    <item>Adana</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Spain">
    <item>Madrid</item>
    <item>Barcelona</item>
</string-array>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input_city);
    countrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input_country);

    countryAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.country_names,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    final String[] country = new String[1];
    countrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
    countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
        {
            country[0] = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView)
        {

        }
    });

    cityAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Turkey,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    cityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    citySpinner.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
```

I need to give a variable inside the `cityAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(...)` line instead of writing Turkey or any country name.

I couldn't come up anything useful in the web, this is my last hope :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                country[0] = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        cityAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Turkey, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        cityAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Madrid, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                        break;
                }
                cityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                citySpinner.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
            }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView < ? > adapterView)
        {

        }
    });
```

Comment: It gives the error **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(int)' on a null object reference** for the line `cityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

Comment: switch 0, 1 sorry not 1 and 2

Comment: I was just doing that :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside first spinner's setonitemselected, declare the second spinner and call clicklistener function i.e, second_spinner.setonitemselectedlistener then the two callback methods will be implemented inside the first spinner's setonitemselected method.